# does string.split() assign variables in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to make a simple program that the user enters a sentence, then inputs a word they would like to replace, then what to replace it with. it then prints the sentence with the new word. This is what I have so far:

```
string = raw_input("Please enter your sentence: ")
splitString = string.split()

print string
```

Does splitstring automatically make variables, if so what are the names?

Comment: No, `splitString` _is_ a variable, created by the assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I`m not used to coding @Amadan ,I meant how can I use string.split() to complete the task.

Comment: You would likely want to ask the user for the word to replace, and the word to replace with. Then you would likely want to iterate over the array of words you have obtained, test the word to see if it is the unwanted one, and replace it by the impostor if so. finally, you would want to `join` the words back together, and print the final sentence out. (It is one of the ways to do it, not nearly the only one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split()` returns a `list`, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> **str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)**
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string (...)

and you can easily check it out by yourself:

```
bruno@bruno:~$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "Hello world"
>>> splitted = s.split()
>>> splitted
['Hello', 'world']
>>> type(splitted)
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

As a general rule: Python's philosophy is that "explicit is better than implicit", so you won't find anything in the stdlib that "automagically" creates variables to get the result of a function. Either a method modify the object in place and returns `None` (ie: `list.sort()` etc) or returns a new object.  Also, since Python strings are immutable, all string methods return an object.